# How do add a youtube video correctly using cordova/phonegap?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, youtube

I have a web app in google play that shows some videos from YouTube. It was working until now, when I received a message saying that my app was removed because it allows the playback on second plan and it violate the therms.

I am using the iframe tag to embed my video with AngularJS framework to do the POST/GET request in YouTube API.

What should I do to not allow the playback on second plan?

Comment: Have you read the documentation about what rules you have violated and what it is you are allowed and not allowed to do? I assume you are referring to the Apple app store?
[https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

Comment: @BradleyFlood sorry, i already edit the post, the app is Google Play.